# GIS extension of Boost.Geometry

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, gis, boost-geometry

I am using Boost 1.50.0 and I need to use the GIS extension of Boost.Geometry. Where can I find this extension for Boost 1.50.0 or lower? (I haven't upgraded my application to newer version of Boost due to some compatibility issues.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extensions are a part of the development version of a library, they're not released. So in order to use them you should probably checkout/clone (and use) the development version of Boost.Geometry. You could also try to mix the released version and the extensions from the development version but I'm guessing this way it'd be easier to make some mistake which would e.g. result in unwanted incompatibilities.

Anyway, the most simple way of doing it would be to see which commit was the most recent one in the Boost.Geometry released in Boost 1.50 (boost-1.50.0 tag in [Boost.Geometry repository on GitHub](https://github.com/boostorg/geometry)):

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/commits/boost-1.50.0

and then try to find a corresponding one in the develop branch:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/commits/develop

Note that you can find some commits in both branches that can't be found in the other. I don't know if that's because SVN was used back then or the reason is different. In your case I'd try with this commit from boost-1.50.0:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/commit/443b01bc07b0fb329aee803ea1bef6a8f14e449b

which seems to correspond to this commit in develop:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/commit/d35eb8f2dff20e61655fcef5ee4a23ca4d9d9847

so this is the develop tree:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/tree/d35eb8f2dff20e61655fcef5ee4a23ca4d9d9847

which you should be able to download by clicking the "Download ZIP" button on the right side of the page. Then you could use it instead of the released version or just extract the extensions from it, etc. Just have in mind it's not officially released version and that no guarantees can be made.

Here you can see the extensions in that tree:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/tree/d35eb8f2dff20e61655fcef5ee4a23ca4d9d9847/include/boost/geometry/extensions